# yii2 Unique Validation(non-ajax) not working

Tags: validation, yii2, unique

I see some links says that Yii2 unique validation is for Ajax validation only(But I dont find any best practice to follow.).So I'm asking this for non ajax validation in Yii2

my model rules are

```
['name', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => 'function_id','message' => 'name must be unique.'],
```

My controller functions are normal actionCreate()

Anybody have solution for this? Thanks in Advance

Edit: For Ajax
ok.I Did,My controller code is now

```
    $model = new JobFunctionRole();
    $model->scenario = 'insert';

    $jobFunction=JobFunction::find()->all();
    if(Yii::$app->request->post()){
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->job_function_role_id]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,'jobFunction'=>$jobFunction
        ]);
    }`
```

But page redirects and shows blank page.

Comment: Do it in Ajax Validation. I Will guide you.

Comment: ok.I Did,My controller code is now:See Edits in my Question.Thanks! :)

Comment: Concectually, In which way you use function_id for check uniqueness?

Comment: @scaisEdge the name is unique based on the function id.ie, [function_id=>2,name=>xxx] same function id with same name xxx should not be enter.btw function_id is not a Primary key here,its reference key of function table

Comment: Then you are meaning that name and function_id must to be unique togheter ?

Answer (score 0):

Could be you must check for both togheter

```
 ['a1', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a1', 'a2']]


[
     'name', 'unique', 
     'targetAttribute' => ['name','function_id'],
      'message' => 'name must be unique.'
],
```

Comment: Thank you!! Works fine.But why its not available for non-ajax actions??

Comment: During ... the validation? or after the validation after commit) ?

Comment: Looking to your controller code .. this could happen if ($model->save()) fails  ...then  for debug try using $model->save(false) (this save the model anyway and then the conditiion became true..